# Multiple environment variable assertion function ternary return type

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

We wanted to create a util function to assert environment variables. We have a project where the devs need certain local env vars that are not required when the application is deployed. In order to streamline the assertions across files I wanted to make this util.
We want to pass either:

- an array of keys required on both local and live; or
- an object with local and live specific env vars and the isLocal value.

If any values that are required are missing, we will throw (assert part)

When all env vars are available, this would return an object with all the values for either the local or live as properties. We then want to be able to use the same isLocal variable we passed to have ts infer the type returned from the assertion method.

We got stuck on the returntype where we want to type the return type depending on the value passed as the "isLocal" property. Last thing we tried was:

```
IEnvConfig<LOCAL, LIVE>['isLocal'] extends true
? Record<LOCAL[number], string>
: Record<LIVE[number], string>
```

But this always evaluates to false. Why?

This is what we currently have:
[Sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-playground-export-forked-pn5n2k?file=%2Findex.ts&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00063b85ewpnjvps%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B83.36717428087987%252C16.632825719120135%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00023b85z1frq4i2%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00033b85mxgffjqe%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00053b85q1m01sd2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B66.83598177812948%252C33.16401822187052%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrfatcve00023b85z1frq4i2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00013b85o20alipi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.env%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfbcurl00703b85iqsnh8ot%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00023b85z1frq4i2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrfbcurl00703b85iqsnh8ot%2522%257D%252C%2522clrfatcve00053b85q1m01sd2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00043b857d4shlgd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00053b85q1m01sd2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00043b857d4shlgd%2522%257D%252C%2522clrfatcve00033b85mxgffjqe%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrfatcve00033b85mxgffjqe%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Please put a [mre] in the question.

Comment: Added an executable codepen and edited original message. I shared the code in the official TS codepen before because I thought the typing would be better for debugging there. hope this one is ok.

Comment: Using a playground is fine, but the MRE needs to be _actually in the question_, not an offsite link. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution typing the return type:

```
type Result<T extends EnvConfigCollection, IsLocal extends boolean> = Record<
  T[number],
  string

> & { isLocal: IsLocal };
```

[answer codepen](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-playground-export-forked-txxyqt?file=%2Findex.ts%3A37%2C29&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00073b84yp7yqr6g%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B87.92035398230088%252C12.079646017699119%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00033b84gqb9whf0%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00043b84totl09fl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00063b84nuazdkka%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B67.24772348907563%252C32.752276510924375%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrffsnaf00033b84gqb9whf0%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00023b84xqvfv928%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A37%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A29%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A37%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A29%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00033b84gqb9whf0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00023b84xqvfv928%2522%257D%252C%2522clrffsnaf00063b84nuazdkka%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00053b84zpqrxa2p%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00063b84nuazdkka%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00053b84zpqrxa2p%2522%257D%252C%2522clrffsnaf00043b84totl09fl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrffsnaf00043b84totl09fl%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)